# jQuery date picker - highlight mutiple selected dates?

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery date picker from http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html and it looks great, but I can't work out how to display specific dates on the calendar as selected?

For example how would I display the following dates as already selected?

3rd May2012, 20th June 20112, 8th Oct 2012 etc.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

```
$(function() {
$('#getSetMultiPicker').datepick({
            multiSelect: 100,
    monthsToShow: 4, 
    monthsToStep: 4,
    prevText: 'Prev months', 
    nextText: 'Next months',
    showTrigger: '#calImg'

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the api it offers a `defaultDate` property.

You could try setting it to an array maybe an array of dates:

```
$(function() {
    $('#getSetMultiPicker').datepick({
        defaultDate: { '5/3/2012', '6/20/11', '10/8/12' }, 
        multiSelect: 100,
        monthsToShow: 4, 
        monthsToStep: 4,
        prevText: 'Prev months', 
        nextText: 'Next months',
        showTrigger: '#calImg'      
    });
});
```

It looks like there is a setter that accepts an array:

```
var dates = { '5/3/2012', '6/20/11', '10/8/12' };

$('#getSetMultiPicker').datepick('setDate', dates);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried the following which seemed to work but if I add more than 2 dates it stops working. $('#getSetMultiPicker').datepick('setDate','07/08/2012','09/07/2012');

Comment: Yea because youre not passing an array look at my second example